# Batch script, file drag&drop, change extension and reload file

Tags: batch-file, drag-and-drop, rename, file-extension

I have a batch script which accepts >=1 files via drag & drop. The full paths are kept in an array and later fed to another program as input. The file name+extension is kept in another array which is then shown to the user.

I am trying to check the file extension and if it is not .bin, automatically rename the file I dragged & dropped to .bin and reload it to be added to the two arrays. How can I do that? I have tried some if commands or %%~xi but usually it doesn't properly detect if it's .bin or not and of course the path is not updated at the array.

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a Count = 0

:START
  set file="%~1"
  if %file%=="" goto RUN
  for %%i in (%file%) do set name=%%~nxi
  set /a Count += 1
  set [FilePath.!Count!]=%file%
  set [FileName.!Count!]=%name%
  shift
goto START

:RUN
for /l %%i in (1, 1, %Count%) do (
   program.exe -command "![FilePath.%%i]!"
   echo.
   echo File Name: ![FileName.%%i]!
   echo.
   pause
   cls
   if exist file.log del file.log
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just rename it during your array population.  There are a few other potential problems with your script (such as `pushd` to an unquoted directory, `delayedexpansion` where you don't need it where it will potentially clobber filenames containing exclamation marks, and `if %file%==""` should have `"%file%"` quoted).  And there's really no reason to maintain an array of filenames or loop twice.  Your script is much more complicated than it needs to be.

```js
@echo off
setlocal

pushd "%~dp0"

for %%I in (%*) do (
    if /I not "%%~xI"==".bin" move "%%~fI" "%%~dpnI.bin" >NUL
    program.exe -command "%%~dpnI.bin"
    echo;
    echo File Name: "%%~nxI"
    echo;

    rem If you want to rename the file back the way it was after running
    rem program.exe on it, uncomment the following line:
    rem if /I not "%%~xI"==".bin" move "%%~dpnI.bin" "%%~fI" >NUL

    pause
    cls
    if exist file.log del file.log
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much rojo, it works perfectly fine. My next concern was about keeping the file with the same extension afterwards which you added as well and works. Now, to check if I understood the changes properly:

1) %I --> the drag & dropped file
2) %* --> condition, will return false after last dropped file?
3) %%~fI --> expands %I to a full path (wasn't it already after %I)?
4) %~dpnI --> expands %I to drive,path,name and adds .bin (desired extension)

Comment: 5) >NUL --> I have read that it supreses the move notification, so it's effect is visual only
6) %~dpnI.bin --> the program is fed %I with correct extension, where is that file (temp folder)?
7) At FileName echo, if %I extension is now renamed properly, can't we use %%~nxI ?

Basically I haven't userstood how the move command of the IF statement worked. Can you explain it please?

Comment: **1:** Yes. **2:** Just loops through all arguments. If there are no arguments, then nothing happens. There's no return. **3:** Yes, but there's no ambiguity with `%%~fI`. **4:** Yes. **5:** Yes. **6:** Same directory. I used `move` rather than `ren` because `ren` chokes if you aren't in the same directory as the file you're renaming. **7:** We aren't modifying the actual variable `%%I`. Think of it as a read-only variable.  We can rename the file it contains, but can't modify the variable itself. So even after the move / rename, `%%I` has the same value as it did at the beginning of the loop.

Comment: **6)** I asked that because I noticed that even after the file is renamed I cannot see the change at the actual file (of course that's not a problem as long as it works). If the file has a new extension and before it's reverted back, why is the difference not visible? **7)** So %%I is not a pointer to a file but a variable with the file path as value. At FileName If I use "%%~nI.bin" it will always add .bin even if a file with no extension is inserted. Since I want it to show the actual file inserted I thought of "%%~nxI". How is "%%~nxI" the wrong string to show?

Comment: **6:** Maybe it's just a matter of the process being too fast to be visible between refreshes of the GUI.  You could add a pause before the final rename and then check things out before continuing if you wish.  **7:** Correct.  `%%I` is not bound to the file and its changes.  On further reflection, `%%~nxI` is not wrong.  I guess the user doesn't need to see that his file is being temporarily renamed.  You're right, that it should probably echo `%%~nxI`.  I'll edit my answer.  Thanks for catching that!

Comment: **6)** Yeap, it happens instantly. I thought that when program.exe runs the batch stays static which is not the case. If you add pause the difference will be visible. **7)** Alright, I am using %%~nxI now and everything is working properly. Thank you rojo for all the help you provided. Indeed the original script was a lot more complicated than it should have been. :)